# Javascript subclass object not retaining properties / methods of base class

Tags: javascript

```
function Man(name){
   this.name = name || 'John';
}
Man.prototype.getName = function(){
   return this.name;
}

function Emp(id){
   this.id = id;
}
Emp.prototype = Object.create(Man.prototype);
Emp.prototype.display = function(){
  return this.id;
}

//Testing

var emp = new Emp(100);
emp.id ; // 100
emp.display() //100
```

However,

```
emp.name // undefined
emp.getName() // undefined

emp instanceof Man // true, proves inheritance
```

Why do `emp.name` and `emp.getName()` come as `undefined`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why do `emp.name` and `emp.getName()` come as `undefined`

Because you are never applying `Man` to the new `Emp` instance. You also have to call the parent constructor in the child constructor:

```
function Emp(id){
   Man.call(this); // call parent constructor
   this.id = id;
}
```

With ECMAScript 6 classes, you would have to call `super`:

```
class Emp extends Man {
    constructor(id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```